# subscribing to an observable inside a behviorSubject: getting error

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I am trying to subscribe to BehaviorSubject and then to an observable depends on a condition

the BehaviorSubject is :

```
orderListSubject= new BehaviorSubject<any>({orderListTouched: false, orderList: []});

myAllOrders = new BehaviorSubject<OrderModel[]>([])
```

I have a service that tries to check if orderListTouched is false, i need to subscribe to another observable to push values to the orderList

The function that will be called if orderListTouched is false :

```
getMyOrderList(){

this.courseService.getMyOrderList(this.user.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe(first())

}
```

here the function that i am trying to use to wrap this case :

```
listenToOrderList(){
    this.courseService.orderListSubject.pipe(map(ev =>{

      return ev.orderListTouched;


    }), switchMap((res)=>{
if(res === false){
return this.getMyOrderList()
}if(res === true){
return this.myAllOrders
}
      
        
      }
      

    }))

  }
```

when i am doing such way I am getting an error : Argument of type '(res: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.

please advise!

Comment: `getMyOrderList()` doesn't return anything. Add a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`getMyOrderList` is missing a `return` statement, hence the complaint about Type 'void'.

```
getMyOrderList(){
  return this.courseService.getMyOrderList(this.user.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe(first());
}
```